# MongoDB update an array element matching _id and multiple conditions within the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I have a MongoDB collections as:

**Collection:**

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64390a7196f544082a671469"),
    "name": "Sydney",
    "issues": [
      {"vol": "2", "num": "1", "freq": 5},
      {"vol": "1", "num": "2", "freq": 7}
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a"),
    "name": "Canton",
    "issues": [
      {"vol": "2", "num": "2", "freq": 9},
      {"vol": "1", "num": "3", "freq": 9},
      {"vol": "2", "num": "1", "freq": 11}
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to update `issues.freq` field matching with the `_id`, `issues.vol` and `issues.num` values.

To be specific, if

1. `_id:ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a")`,
2. `issue.vol:"2"` and
3. `issue.num:"1"`

`issue.freq` will be updated to `45` (from existing value of `11`).

Here is the query that I have arrived so far:

**Query:**

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a"),
  "issues.vol": "2",
  "issues.num": "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "issues.$.freq": 45
  }
})
```

The problem is, it updates the value for (`"_id": ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a")`, `"issues.vol": "2"` and `"issues.num": "2"`) instead of (`"_id": ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a")`, `"issues.vol": "2"` and `"issues.num": "1"`). What am I doing wrong?

**Result set (after my query above):**

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64390a7196f544082a671469"),
    "issues": [
      {"freq": 5, "num": "1", "vol": "2"},
      {"freq": 7, "num": "2","vol": "1"}
    ],
    "name": "Sydney"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a"),
    "issues": [
      {"freq": 45, "num": "2", "vol": "2"},
      {"freq": 9, "num": "3", "vol": "1"},
      {"freq": 11, "num": "1", "vol": "2"}
    ],
    "name": "Canton"
  }
]
```

[Mongo playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z7mg4POCsUy)

So many thanks for reading this far. I would also like to extend my gratitude if you have given some thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with positional filtered operator [`$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update specific element(s) in an array.

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a"),
  "issues.vol": "2",
  "issues.num": "1"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "issues.$[i].freq": 45
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "i.vol": "2",
      "i.num": "1"
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1GPDsupm9Qc)

Comment: Is setting `"issues.vol": "2",  "issues.num": "1"` in initial condition necessary? I can see it works without those.

Comment: Hi @sariDon, *Is setting "issues.vol": "2",  "issues.num": "1" in initial condition necessary*, would say it depends. Without both field filters, it will only find the document that matches with id. And still it will check whether there is any element in the array that fulfill the criteria in the `arrayFilters` and next update if it exists.

Comment: As you wrote your answer with PyMongo, I assume that you are using PyMongo. So if you debug the [results](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html) returned from `update`. The `matched_count` could be returned different value if you filter only with `_id` or filter with `_id`, `issues.vol` and `issues.num`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have adjusted the code according to your advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Corresponding PyMongo query:**

If it helps anyone working with PyMongo (Note: `arrayFilters` of MongoDB becomes `array_filters` in PyMongo):

```
import bson

edvol= "2"
ednum= "1"
per_col.update_one(
    {
        '_id': bson.ObjectId("64390a8796f544082a67146a"),
        "issues.vol": edvol,
        "issues.num": ednum
    }, 
    {'$set': {"issues.$[i].freq": 45}}, 
    upsert=False,
    array_filters=[{'i.vol': edvol, 'i.num': ednum}]
)
```